# Elasticsearch more_like_this query exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, elasticsearch, multi-index

Trying to use ElasticSearch more_like_this query in my RoR application. I have different indexes set up for different environments, having search_development and search_staging accordingly.

When executing a MLT query on the staging environment (both via CURL or via Rails console) everything seems fine - records are returned.

When doing the same in development environment, the result set was always empty. I figured that had something to do with data versions, so I tried recreating the index from scratch. Now as I've done that, querying MLT throws an exception:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[UvOf1vxTR6WNICxTzIdJ1g][search_development][2]: SearchParseException[[search_development][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"more_like_this\":{\"ids\":[\"1\"],\"fields\":[\"title\",\"description\"]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[search_development] ambiguous type for item with id: 1 and index: search_development]; }
```

This happens both via CURL and Rails console. The same exact query works fine on staging index. When checking, the records are in the index, the data is there too. The query_string query is working fine just as it did before.

There's clearly something I'm missing with the multi-index part of elasticsearch or MLT query, because before recreating the index, the query wasn't returning results (while the same exact query worked fine on staging index). I must add that the staging index has over a thousand records, while development has only 14.

The query is:

```
curl -XGET 'http://asdf:9200/search_development/_search' -d '{ "query": {"more_like_this": {"ids": ["1"], "fields": ["title","description"]}} }'
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have the same issue! :)

Comment: It had something to do with the type of the document. I started using types for documents and the issue was gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two potential issues:

1. You are not specifying the type in the request URL. To search a single type (which would make the "id" field unambiguous), use one more param in the url:

`curl -XGET 'http://asdf:9200/search_development/my_type/_search' -d '{ "query": {"more_like_this": {"ids": ["1"], "fields": ["title","description"]}} }'`

2. If you do want to search multiple types, you may want to use the `docs:` syntax for the `more_like_this` query [detailed here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html). This is similar to the [multi-get API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html). The `docs` syntax allows you to specify an `index:` and `type:` for each document to analyze, sparing Elasticsearch the ambiguity.

`curl -XGET 'http://asdf:9200/search_development/_search' -d '{ "query": {"more_like_this": {"fields": ["title","description"], "docs": [{"_index": "search_development", "_type": "my_type", "_id": "1" }}}'`

**warning** I haven't actually done this, so I'm not sure, but I suspect that will fix the issue.

Comment: Your answer is pretty accurate. I did solve the issue by supplying the document type to the query.